# Rails 4.Combine 2 arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have 2 arrays and I want to combine them in one which should return nested JSON.
The first one is cleaner which returns:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Fernando",
      "last_name": "Gomez",
      "avg_rating": "4.5"
    }  
  ]
}
```

The second one is reviews from the clients
which returns the name of the client, comment and rating:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "score": 4,
      "comment": "Comment",
      "first_name": "John Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, I trie to zip them and loop over each of them. Here is my code:

```
cleaners.zip(reviews).each do |cleaner, review|
  if cleaner.id == review.id
   test['first_name'] = cleaner.first_name
   test['last_name'] = cleaner.last_name
   test['rating'] = review.score
   test['comment'] = review.comment
   test['client_name'] = review.first_name
  end
end
```

The result is:

```
{
  "response": {
    "first_name": "Fernando",
    "last_name": "Gomez",
    "rating": 4,
    "comment": "Comment",
    "client_name": "John Doe"
  }
}
```

But my result has to be nested because some of the cleaners will have many reviews. It has to be something like this:

```
{
  "response": {
    "first_name": "Fernando",
    "last_name": "Gomez",
    "score_from_client": [
                {
                  "rating": 4,
                  "comment": "Comment",
                 "client_name": "John Doe"
                }
                ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't they have a relationship defined in the model?

Comment: Yes all this arrays are filled from sql queries becouse, cleaners have work in specific period of time, job_types and many more.Also client can ban cleaners.

Comment: What I meant is: do they have a has_many / belongs_to relationship through which you are getting them? In that case it should be really simple

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of the question :)

```
unless cleaners.nil?



cleaner_ids = []
  cleaners_reviews = []

  cleaners.each do |cleaner|
    cleaner_review = { 
      id:  cleaner.id,
      avg_rating:  cleaner.avg_rating,
      first_name:  cleaner.first_name,
      last_name:  cleaner.last_name,
      ratings: []
    }
    cleaners_reviews << cleaner_review
    cleaner_ids << cleaner.id
  end

  reviews = Cleaner.get_cleaner_reviews(dates, cleaner_ids)

  unless reviews.empty?
    i = 0
    reviews.each do |review|
      cleaners_reviews[i][:ratings] << review
      i += i
    end
  end

  return cleaners_review
```

s